# How to use SAMBA on an Amazon S3 mounted directory on Ubuntu VM

Tags: samba, amazon-s3, s3fs

I had successfully configured a SAMBA share on **/home/myusername** on an **Ubuntu 17.10 VM**. I then used **s3fs-fuse** to mount an S3 bucket on that exact directory, i.e. /home/myusername. It worked too, any files I created in this directory were created in my S3 bucket.

However, I am no longer able to access my samba share. I am able to connect to the SAMBA server and connect to other shares, but not the one on /home/username. It shows

> Windows cannot access \IP-Address\share.
>
> You do not have permission to access \\IP-Address\share. Contact your network administrator to request access.

I could assume that, on mounting the S3 bucket, the username used to connect to SAMBA lost access permissions to the directory, but that seemed unlikely, as the directory is the home directory of the user.

Since SAMBA uses its own userbase instead of the system user accounts, do I need to grant permissions to some other user also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem. By default s3fs blocks other users from accessing the bucket. Had to make two changes:

1. Uncomment **user_allow_other** in /etc/fuse.conf
2. While mounting, add **-o allow_other** in the command

> s3fs *bucketname /local/path* -ourl=https://s3.amazonaws.com **-o allow_other**